# How to search for a group having the gid?

Tags: c, linux

Basically, I need to write C code which prompts user to write a gid and then it searches for the group with the given gid
If the group exists, it prints username, uid, gid, gecos and home directory
I can only use system calls

I wrote the following code but I always get that group doesn't exist

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pwd.h>
#include<grp.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
struct passwd *pw;
struct group *grp;
gid_t gid;
int dim,i;


write(1,"Inserire il gid da cercare: ",strlen("Inserire il gid da cercare: "));
read(0,&gid,sizeof(gid_t));
write(1,"\nHai inserito il seguente gid: ",strlen("\nHai inserito il seguente gid: "));
write(1,&gid,sizeof(gid));
setgrent();
while((grp=getgrent())!=NULL && gid!=grp->gr_gid){

}
if(grp==NULL)
    write(2,"\nIl gruppo inserito non esiste!\n",strlen("\nIl gruppo inserito non esiste!\n"));
else if(gid==grp->gr_gid){
    write(1,"\nNome utente= ",strlen("\nNome utente= "));
    write(1,pw->pw_name,sizeof(pw->pw_name));
    write(1,", ",strlen(", "));
    write(1,"Uid= ",strlen("Uid= "));
    write(1,&pw->pw_uid,sizeof(pw->pw_uid));
    write(1,", ",strlen(", "));
    write(1,"Gid= ",strlen("Gid= "));
    write(1,&pw->pw_gid,sizeof(pw->pw_gid));
    write(1,", ",strlen(", "));
    write(1,"Gecos= ",strlen("Gecos= "));
    write(1,pw->pw_gecos,sizeof(pw->pw_gecos));
    write(1,", ",strlen(", "));
    write(1,"Home= ",strlen("Home= "));
    write(1,pw->pw_dir,sizeof(pw->pw_dir));
    write(1,"\n",strlen("\n"));
}
endgrent();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What's wrong with `getgrgid`. `getgrent` isn't a system call either.

Comment: Also, the user inserts a decimal number, but `gid_t` is an integer! Use `scanf`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `strlen()` is a compiler intrinsic, it is going to be evaluated into a constant on any decent compiler including Linux. Please do fact checking on your comments before guiding others.

Comment: I can't use scanf, printf or similars, only read and write

I know about strlen being not efficient but it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @rafc so what is this silly exercise then restricting? What can you actually use?! `getgrent` is a library function, you can't use it. Can you use `strtol` to convert the gid into a number, or `strcmp`?

Comment: @Antti, I believe at best they are replaced with inline insructions. Clever compilers may evaluate this to constants. Stupid compilers call library functions. Programmers beginning to program do not know this and are wasting machine cycles when programming like this.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the exercise is about being familiar with /etc/group and /etc/passwd and yes I can use strtol strcmp and similars

anyway, is gid an integer?

Comment: If the exercise is to learn about e.g. `getgrent` and family, then why put limitations on the *standard C* functions that can be used for *input*? That makes no sense.

Comment: Also, while the use of file descriptors `0` to `2` are well-known, please avoid to use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). Use e.g. `STDIN_FILENO` for standard input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you read your input:

```
read(0,&gid,sizeof(gid_t));
```

This reads the binary representation of ***the textual input***.

So if you input the e.g. `1250` as input, the value of `gid` will be `0x31323530` (using [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) and little endianness).

You should read a *string* and the convert it to an integer value. ***Or*** use the standard C function `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &gid);
```

Comment: I can't use scanf, printf and similars, so could this be legit?
char *input;
    int dim,i;

    input=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    write(1,"Inserire il gid da cercare: ",strlen("Inserire il gid da cercare: "));
    read(0,input,sizeof(input));
    write(1,"\nHai inserito il seguente gid: ",strlen("\nHai inserito il seguente gid: "));
    write(1,input,sizeof(input));
    gid=atoi(input);
    setgrent();

Comment: @rafc Two problems: `input` in your comment is not a pointer, and doing `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the pointer and not what it points to. Why allocate dynamically to begin with, why not use arrays? Also remember that strings in C are actually called ***null terminated** byte strings*. So remember to have space for (and add) the terminator.

Comment: I don't know why but when I comment stars get removed... I wrote char (star)input and also the malloc in (char star) etc...